# How do I look inside the NLTK classifier train method

Tags: nltk

I've been looking at Laurent Luce's' blog on sentiment analysis.  Unfortunately I have not been able to follow his blog so I cannot ask him a question directly.  Here is the link to the blog: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/

Pretty much everything works nicely. However I cannot figure out how to get this part to work - text below is pasted from the link. My question is how do I look inside the classifier train method? It will help my understanding if I could do that.

"Let’s take a look inside the classifier train method in the source code of the NLTK library. ‘label_probdist’ is the prior probability of each label and ‘feature_probdist’ is the feature/value probability dictionary. Those two probability objects are used to create the classifier."

```
def train(labeled_featuresets, estimator=ELEProbDist):
...
# Create the P(label) distribution
label_probdist = estimator(label_freqdist)
...
# Create the P(fval|label, fname) distribution
feature_probdist = {}
...
return NaiveBayesClassifier(label_probdist, feature_probdist)
```

Answer (score 0):

NLTK is open source. You can find the source-code [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk). Github has solid search functionality, so you should be able to find whatever it is you need using that. Specifically, the naive bayes classifier is [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/79ef1cfb4c5dcc8543c465aba8b34aa0878e738b/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py)
and you can see the train method for it in that file.